# How to find most repeat elements in lists?

Tags: python, counter

```
def print_most_numbers_occurrences(numbers_str):
    number_list = numbers_str.split() 
    for i in number_list:
        i=max(number_list,key=number_list.count)
    print(i)


def test_print_most_numbers_occurrences():
     print_most_numbers_occurrences('2 3 40 1 5 4 3 3 9  9')
     print_most_numbers_occurrences('9 30 3 9 3 1 4')
     print_most_numbers_occurrences('19 30 13 4 9 3 1 4')

def main():
    test_print_most_numbers_occurrences()


main()
```

output:

```
3
9
4
```

I want to get **all** most repeating numbers for `'9 30 3 9 3 1 4'`: 9 and 3 appear twice, so both occurrences should be reported not only `9`

output looks like this:

```
3
9
3
4
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation and formatting.

Comment: And what does "double max number" mean?

Comment: what's a "double max number"? Also it's a bit hard to follow your question. What's the problem?

Comment: 9 and 3 appear twice,so both occurrences should be reported.

Comment: Check out `collections.Counter`, it will make things nicer.

Comment: @poke Wrong duplicate. This question explicitly asks for the most repeated elements - plural (no tie-breakers, it should report all elements that have the maximum count).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: You don't need the `for`-loop when you use `max`. It already does that for you.

Second: If you want to have more than one value then `max` isn't really a good choice. For these kind of counting operations you should use `collections.Counter` (it also avoids counting the number of occurrences multiple times).

```
from collections import Counter

def print_most_numbers_occurrences(numbers_str):
    number_list = numbers_str.split() 
    # count the occurrences
    cnts = Counter(number_list)
    # Get the maximum count
    maximum_cnt = max(cnts.values())
    # print all values that have the "maximum" count
    print(*[val for val, cnt in cnts.items() if cnt == maximum_cnt])
```

And the test with your inputs prints:

```
3
9 3
4
```

If you prefer simple loops over comprehensions (or you use python-2.x without the `print` function) you could also use:

```
def print_most_numbers_occurrences(numbers_str):
    number_list = numbers_str.split() 
    cnts = Counter(number_list)
    maximum_cnt = max(cnts.values())
    for value, cnt in cnts.items():
        if cnt == maximum_cnt:
            print(value)
```

which gives:

```
3
9
3
4
```

Comment: I was expecting `[(_, maximum_cnt)] = cnts.most_common(1)` to be faster than `maximum_cnt = max(cnts.values())` but surprisingly it was not.

Comment: `most_common` does a [full sort or (partial) heap-sort](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L544-L555) based on the values. So it doesn't really surprise me that `max` is faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

a = ('2 3 40 1 5 4 3 3 9  9','9 30 3 9 3 1 4','19 30 13 4 9 3 1 4')

for x in a:
    x = x.split()
    b = Counter(x)
    z = max(b.values())
    for k in b.keys():
        if b[k] == z:
            print(k)
```

output:

```
3
9
3
4
```

**If you want another output**

```
from collections import Counter

a = ('2 3 40 1 5 4 3 3 9  9','9 30 3 9 3 1 4','19 30 13 4 9 3 1 4')

k = []
for x in a:
    x = x.split()
    b = Counter(x)
    z = max(b.values())
    k.append([f for f in b.keys() if b[f] == z])

print(k)
```

output

```
[['3'], ['9', '3'], ['4']]
```

**Using a function**

```
from collections import Counter

def maxmy(sequences):
    k = []
    for x in sequences:
        x = x.split()
        b = Counter(x)
        z = max(b.values())
        k.append([f for f in b.keys() if b[f] == z])
    return k

maxmy(('2 3 40 1 5 4 3 3 9  9','9 30 3 9 3 1 4','19 30 13 4 9 3 1 4'))
```

output

```
[['3'], ['9', '3'], ['4']]
```